# Solution of $\Pi(y(x)+1)+\sin(x)=y(x)+y'(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

How do we solve $$\Pi(y(x)+1)+\sin(x)=y(x)+y'(x)$$
I suspect it will be a function of many cases. The solution of $$\Pi(x+1)+\sin(x)=y(x)+y'(x)$$ is hard only at the evaluation of the last integral which requires 3 cases, but what happens if $y(x)$ is in the rectangular function?

Comment: What is the definition of $\Pi(x)$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function

Comment: Also, do you have an initial condition given?

Comment: No, the initial problem was the second DE I posted, I just wondered if there is a way to solve it with $y(x)$ in $\Pi(\cdot)$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Such type of problems is a good reason to study the books like this: A.F. Filippov "Differential Equations with Discontinuous Righthand Sides",  http://books.google.ru/books/about/Differential_Equations_with_Discontinuou.html?id=KBDyZSwpQpQC&redir_esc=y

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? They are important here. Maybe the rectangular function never kicks in.

Comment: No boundary conditions, that's the reason I suspect many cases.